# java write to existing xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to add some data into an existing xml file.This is what i have done:

```
try {
    String filepath = "/askhsh3/WebContent/askisi3.xml";
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

    // Get the root element
    Node rootn = doc.getFirstChild();

    //Node staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff").item(0);

    // append a new node to staff
    Document doc2 = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element patient = doc2.createElement("patient");

    Element st_as = doc.createElement("stoixeia_astheni");
    for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
        Element tmp= doc2.createElement(elem[i]);
        tmp.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("aaa"));
        st_as.appendChild(tmp);
    }

    patient.appendChild(st_as);
    rootn.appendChild(patient);
    doc.appendChild(rootn);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException sae) {
    sae.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to create some text nodes into an existing xml.

Comment: @MBanerjee nothing change on xml file..this is a web project built in eclipse,askhsh3 is the name of the project and `/workspace/askhsh/WebContent/askisi3.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are modifying the xml document in memory, but you are not saving it back to the file, and that doesn't happen automatically. You need to explicitly write it. Here is some example code:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));
```

Comment: how can i change the permission of the file? i am running tomcat from eclipse and the paths are relative to the project

Comment: @user2420697 not sure about that, you can ask a separate question. Also you should specify what error you are getting.